# Good place to start for encryption algorithms

Tags: encryption

I have a school project which I still have a week left to complete which is done per specification. Part of this project is an encryption portion which the instructions we were instructed to do a simple XOR "encryption" for. (I realize this hardly qualifies as encryption)

This is done, but I figured I have a week and I might as well challenge myself, trying to put together something that isn't completely terrible for the encryption. Looking for recommendations on where to start for that. I looked at a couple (AES, RC5) and found myself totally in over my head. Looking for a place to start to start wrapping my head around this stuff.

Thanks

Comment: you can start with simple DES (not 3DES)

Comment: Do not start with DES, go with AES. (DES should not be used and is not easier than AES). What language are you using?

Comment: @zaph DES has simplified version (SDES) which was especially created for students

Comment: @zaph class is 100% c++

Comment: I guess the question is developing the code for an encryption algorithm or using one. There is also [XTEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA) which is super short.

Comment: @zaph Agree, if you just have learned about XOR encryption then a stream cipher is a logical next step, and stream ciphers are often pretty easy to implement (compared to most block ciphers anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encrypt using a one-time-pad (OTP). That's uber simple. First create and distribute (out of band) a very large, completely random key. Then XOR each bit of the plaintext with a bit of the very large key at the same position. This scheme is perfectly secure (besides leaking the size of the plaintext).

In practice this is very impractical because of the key size. Furthermore, it is almost impossible to create a *completely random* key. But you can simply use any cryptographically secure random number generator to achieve a practical level of security.

Decryption is the same as encryption: just XOR the key with the ciphertext to retrieve the plaintext.

---

I slightly misread the question, giving you XOR encryption (although now completely secure). You could create a simple stream cipher. In that case you use another algorithm, say [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4), to create the key stream from a smaller key. The key stream is then used to basically create the key you use to perform OTP encryption with. Note that RC4 is somewhat insecure. You might want to look at e.g. Spritz (mentioned on the RC4 Wikipedia entry) which should be almost as easy to implement.

Alternatively, as zaph already mentioned, you could also try [XTEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA).

---

Alternatively you may just take an AES implementation and play around with [modes of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). Implementing a cipher is fun, but in general knowing how to *use* a cipher is more practical for developers.

Comment: The issue is "distribute (out of band) a very large, completely random key" that can only be used once. Perhaps via snail mail.

Comment: Hmm, I think I misread the question. Then again if you already have XOR encryption you might as well do this...